# How to run a .py file in windows command line?

Tags: python, command-line

I have written a simple python program using IDLE to run it from command line. I don't have permission to save .py file in python directory (C:\program files\python33) so I saved it to C:\Pyscripts.

Also python was already been added to the PATH and I can run a simple `print ("Hello")` in command line. I have saved this line into a py file and Now I want to run it from command prompt but I have faced different errors! I have searched and tested different ways but they didn't work!

any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. What errors? 2. "I can run simple print ("Hello")" - so, what can you run and what can't you run?

Comment: If it executes with errors, the problem is probably with your code, and having nothing to do with the execution environment. If you post code and errors, perhaps we can help.

Comment: When I type print ("Hello") in commandline, there is no problem. But when I write it in IDLE, save it as py file and then face error when run it from command prompt.

Comment: Imagine I have a .py file in directory mentioned above and I want to run it in windows commandline, but I can't. How can I do it?

Comment: @MACEE What do you have in your file? How are you trying to run it (which command do you use, are you in the right directory in your prompt)? What is the error?

Comment: I have `print ("Hello")` in test.py file. I saved it to C:\Pyscripts. In command line, I did this: C:\Users\MACEE>cd C:\Pyscripts

Comment: Show us exactly what you typed and exactly what happened as a result.  Don't describe it, show it :-)

Comment: Then: C:\Pyscripts>python  and finally >>>test.py

Comment: I face this error:  NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Comment: You are part way there - you are running the .py file and getting a python error. You have the word "test" in test.py. You claim that file contains the single line `print ("hello")`. Delete everything else (or post the entire contents of test.py for us to see).

Comment: @sashkello I've got this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @sashkello's requirement to run `python test.py` isn't needed. You ran python when you entered `test.py` and in fact, just `test` would work.

Comment: Yoou should try this tutorial. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: You said NameError and now you say SyntaxError. You are changing the code! If you just have the line `print("hello")`, it will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Start cmd.exe
2. `cd C:\Pyscripts`
3. `python filename.py`

For basics like `print 'hello'`, you don't need any library import statements but for slightly more complex things you will.

Which python do you have installed?

1. You don't want to save files in c:\program files under windows. That isn't a good practice. Setting up a dev directory like you did or under your user directory is a much better option.
2. Have you added python to the path setting? If you start a command prompt (cmd.exe, not IDLE and type `python`, what do you get? If you haven't set the python path, see http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html or
   http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/setting-up-windows-python-path-system-variable.php. Just update the settings to the version of python you are using e.g c:\python27.
3. Get a text editor instead of using IDLE. textpad, textedit, vim, emacs ,context, geanie, sublime, and many many more. Or get an IDE. Aptana's studio 3 is easy to use and free (eclipse with plugins already installed) or the free community version of pycharm.

Comment: Generally, you don't need to preface with "python" on windows.

Comment: I  just did this 2 line:  start cmd.exe

cd C:\Pyscripts python filename.py   and I've got this error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: I find it avoids confusion when teaching people and avoids hassles if they have installed multiple versions.Also because something works on windows a certain way doesn't mean its a good practice.

Comment: I have Python 3.3.2 and when I have added python to the path setting. when I start a command prompt and type python I've got this: python 3.3.2 (....)....Type "help", "" , ....

Comment: @MACEE did you type the exact phrase "python filename.py" or did you substitute in your _actual_ filename? If you just wrote filename.py, it's no surprise the system cannot find the path specified....

Comment: @desiredlogin login I exactly did this: start cmd.exe

cd C:\Pyscripts

python test.py  but I've got the error!

Comment: @MACCEE in the command prompt type: python filename.py  which will run your program. Once the command prompt box has started type cd C:\Pyscripts thenpress return. Then type python test.py

Comment: @MACEE - the `cd c:\Pyscripts python filename` trick doesn't work. Its been changed in this answer.

Comment: So.... You cd to the directory. THEN run python test.py, right? You're not putting those commands all on one line?

Comment: @JAL No, not all toghether.. first using cd C:\Pyscripts then Enter, then python test.py

Comment: Okay, just making sure!

Comment: I just want to try running python programs from command line with a very simple py file(print ("Hello!")), BUT I don't know why it gets this much complicated!

Comment: @MACEE try this (all on one line) set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\python33;c:\python33\libs;C:\Pyscripts  now press return          Just check the directories you installed to. This will only work for the commandline session and the setting is lost when you close the commandprompt.

Comment: @lxx why do you suggest to change the text editor? what's wrong with IDLE?

Comment: @MACEE what did you set your python path to ? (what did you add to the path setting in environment variables?)

Comment: @MACEE nothing wrong with idle but using a plain text editor is simpler and can avoid saving some extra characters some times as idle tends to save all the commandline characters (including >>> ) not just the commands you typed.

Comment: @lxx I tried it and got this error: 'PYTHONPATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @MACCEE try set PYTHONPATH = C:\python33;c:\python33\libs;C:\Pyscripts

Comment: I have a 'Path' variable which its value is 'C:\Python33\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\QuickTime\QTSystem\'

Comment: @MACCEE you still need to add Libs directory and system packages. eg.For python 2.7 I have  C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;

Comment: @lxx I have added all this to 'Path'. then I tried cd C:\Pyscripts and then python and then test.py but it says NameError:....!

Comment: @lxx you are right, I just opened the test.py file in IDLE and delete extra characters and just `print ("Hello")` remains in file. then simply run it in command line and it works!!!

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is that you should take a basic tutorial on using the interpreter and/or using python modules. For example: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way to create and run a one-line test script from the command prompt:

```
C:\>cd \Pyscripts
C:\Pyscripts>echo print("hello") > mytest.py
C:\Pyscripts>mytest
hello
```

Try it and if it fails on your system, post the result. This is a good sanity check for your system configuration.

(EDIT) Why your original file doesn't work: When you run idle, it starts with an interactive session, something like:

```
ActivePython 3.2.2.3 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.2.2 (default, Sep  8 2011, 10:55:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print("hello")
hello
>>>
```

When you save this (File >> Save), you've saved the full shell session output, not just the script you wrote. Instead, you should select (File >> New Window) which will bring up a text editor, add your code and save that. You can use any text editor, not just idle, for this step.

Comment: @MACEE - assuming your program is small, edit your question and paste it in as a code block.

Comment: Thanks, That's helpful.